# Is it safe to play the Macbook Pro/Air speakers at maximum volume?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, sound-volume

The Macbook Pro speakers have a very crisp sound. I like to play them at almost max. volume very often.

- Will the speakers suffer a loss in quality?
- Is this save to use on the long run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cones in almost any speaker will break down over time. Various environmental factors will determine how long a speaker lasts, but overdriving the element can definitely have an adverse effect.

It's impossible to provide any precise data but in short, you're probably *shortening* the life of the speakers (by an indeterminate amount of time) by running them at maximum volume but, provided you're not hearing any distortion from the speakers, you're not *damaging* them by doing so.

Comment: I recognize that there is a subtle distinction between *shortening the life of* and *damaging* but can't (at the moment) think of a better way of expressing my thought. Anyone?

Comment: The language is fine. I think everybody gets your point (at least, if I do)! Thanks @jaberg